# Не отображается картинка в webview если сервер требует логина

Tags: android, auth, android-webview, аутентификация

В `WebView` андроид-приложения заливаю контент в котором есть ссылки на картинки которые лежат на серверах.

Если сервер не требует логина и пароля для входа - то все ок - картинки загружаются и отображаются.
Но если к серверу требуется доступ с логином и паролем - то картинки не отображаются.

**Кусок кода WebView в onCreate:**

```
web = webLayout.findViewById(R.id.content);

WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
settings.setTextZoom(storage.getTextZoom());
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

web.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

web.loadDataWithBaseURL("",
        content,
        "text/html",
        "utf-8",
        null);
```

**Сам `сontent` который заливаю выглядит так:**

```
<html>

    <head>
    <style> body { margin: 0; padding: 16; font-family: sans-serif-light, sans-serif; word-wrap: break-word;} P:first-letter {  margin-left: 20px;  }  img { margin-left: -16; margin-right: -16; display: inline; height: auto !important; max-width: 100vw; } </style>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script> function myFunctionGet(s) { android.getUri(s); } </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        //какой-то текст.....

        <img onclick="myFunctionGet(this.src)" src="http://88.888.88.8:8888/uploads/11368/18797рdc3b.jpg" style="height:238px; width:400px"/>

        //еще какой-то текст.....

    </body>

</html>
```

**Пробовал такие способы:**

**1)** Перед вставкой в `WebView` прописывать в путь картинки логин и пароль по типу:

```
<img onclick="myFunctionGet(this.src)" src="http://username:password@88.888.88.8:8888/uploads/11368/18797рdc3b.jpg" style="height:238px; width:400px"/>
```

**2)** Добавлять кастомный `WebViewClient` c аутентификацией через `HttpAuthHandler`:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
            HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);

        handler.proceed("username", "password");

    }
}
```

Но эти варианты не дали нужного результата.
Как решить даную проблему?

Comment: А как у вас на сервере проходит авторизация? Возщможно вам просто нужно передать логин и пароль в хедере в зашифрованном виде и с соответствующими заголовками или может сначала нужно получить токен, а потом с ним идти за картинкой?!

Comment: @Valeriy если я в браузере открываю ссылку типа http : //username:password@88.888.88.8:8888/uploads/11368/18797рdc3b.jpg  - картинкаоткрывается.  Если же : http : //88.888.88.8:8888/uploads/11368/18797рdc3b.jpg - то выводится окно для авторизации.

Comment: @Valeriy Можете пример привести относительно: "...нужно передать логин и пароль в хедере в зашифрованном виде и с соответствующими заголовками" ?  А то я я не очень понял как это реализовать.

Comment: Для начала надо выяснить какая именно у сервера аутентификация. Потом подстроиться под это правило.

Comment: @woesss Подскажите пожалуйста, какой вопрос задать бекэндщику что бы это узнать? Или можно самому это выяснить?

Comment: Стоп! - если это приложение для общего пользования, а не для личных целей, то вы должны залогинить на этом сервере юзера, а не подставлять свой логин и пароль. Иначе вы очень быстро теряете аккаунт, и самое страшное - все юзеры не увидят картинки до тех пор, пока вы не выпустите обновление (и снова увод акка и всё по-новой). Либо брать картинки через собственный промежуточный сервер, с которого злоумышленник не сможет увести пароль. Или договориться с бэкэндом на получение их без логина (если такое уместно).

Comment: @woesss Картинки норм отображаются если приложение используется юзерами , так как картинки лежат на открытом сервере. Но вот разработка ведется на закрытом сервере. И когда приложение в руках разработчика, то должно отобразить картинки с закрытого сервера. Потому приходится делать вилку между дебаг и релиз версиями приложения. По  причине сохранения конфиденциальности и не отобразил в вопросе реальный сервер и логин/пароль.

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке `WebView` можно передавать свои данные в хедерах как уже говорил [Valeriy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238266/valeriy). Для этого вам нужно использовать `HashMap<String, String>()`. Вот например что я использую у себя в проекте:

```
val bearer = "Bearer " + context!!.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!
val headerMap = HashMap<String, String>()
headerMap["Authorization"] = bearer
```

и дальше прикрепляю его при загрузке webview:

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(url, headerMap)

                return true
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                swipe.isRefreshing = false
            }

            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
                return null

            }

            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                swipe.isRefreshing = true
            }
        }
```

и загружаю страницу:

```
 webView.loadUrl(link, headerMap)
```

вот пример на `Java`:

```
WebView  host = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
String url = "<yoururladdress>";

Map <String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
extraHeaders.put("Authorization","Bearer"); 
host.loadUrl(url,extraHeaders);
```

Вы должны в вашем случае передавать login и password при загрузке страницы.

Comment: Спасибо конечно за рекомендацию. Я этим успешно пользуюсь когда получаю страницу ретрофитом передавая при запросе логин и пароль (аналогично передаче аутентификатора через хеадер). Это абсолютно не проблема.  Дело в том что я загружаю контент в WebView УЖЕ ПОСЛЕ  УДАЧНОГО ПОЛУЧЕНИЯ СТРАНИЦЫ. То есть, я НЕ загружаю в WebView с URL-а,  а запихиваю туда стринг с html структурой в котором есть ссылки. Я это описал в вопросе.

Comment: Значит нужно вручную прилепить к адресу данные

Comment: Это было первым что я сделал.

Comment: username:password@ просто добавил перед тем как пушить в webview.  Но что-то упустил.  Или же данный способ неподходит...

Comment: Или Вы о других данных и о другом способе их прилепить к адресу?